# How can i test my if statement so it will be code covered?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I have this function

```
testing(x) {
      if(x == 10) {
        return 10;
      }
  }
```

so my test looks like this

```
 it('testing function', () => {
    expect(component.testing(10)).toBe(10);
  })
```

and it passes but the problem is that when i run `code-coverage` than i see that code coverage is descresed because of this if statement - so i can't find a way how can i test
this if statement so the `branch` coverage will be fine

Comment: what if you return x outside your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to test for when x is not 10 to get full code coverage.

Comment: Agree, Add opposite (else) condition also to get full coverage.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I t resolved my issue, But why i need to test wheb x is not 10 when i don't have else condition in my function ?

Comment: @JohnJS you have an _implicit_ else condition - if `x != 10` (you should [really use](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq) `===`/`!==`, by the way), then `testing` returns `undefined`.